# Sequencia de videos em mp4

Tags: javascript, html

Ola boa atarde a todos gostaria que esse código fizesse sequencia apos um 1 video automaticamente ir para o segundo alguém pode me ajudar `

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.MenuBox {
    -moz-border-radius:30px;
    -webkit-border-radius:30px;
    border-radius:30px;
    border: #solid 10px #000;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    width:fixed;
    height:auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:10px;
}
.MenuBox:before,
.MenuBox:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.MenuBox:after {
  clear: both;
}
#videoarea {
  float: left;
    width:630px;
    height:350px;
}
#playlist {
  float: left;
}
#playlist li{
    cursor:pointer;
}
#playlist li:hover{
    color:blue;                        
}
</style>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
        $("#videoarea").attr({
            "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
            "poster": "",
            "autoplay": "autoplay"
        })
    })
    $("#videoarea").attr({
        "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
        "poster": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("moviesposter")
    })
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="MenuBox">
<video id="videoarea" controls="controls" poster="" autoplay="true" src=""></video>
<ul id="playlist">
    <li movieurl="1.mp4">SnK</li>
    <li movieurl="2.mp4">Titanic Titanic Titanic Titanic Titanic Titanic </li>

</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adicione o atributo `"loop": "loop"` (e de quebra atualize este jquery ai né, esta muito defasado).

```
$(function() {
    $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
        $("#videoarea").attr({
            "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
            "poster": "",
            "autoplay": "autoplay",
            "loop": "loop"
        })
    })
    $("#videoarea").attr({
        "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
        "poster": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("moviesposter")
    })
})
```